# Speeding up LINQ to EF queries to max

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a DB table with large amounts of records, I'm expecting it to rise up to 900 million - 1 billion records at a certain point.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to speed up my LINQ to SQL queries which currently looks like this:

```
var allProducts = ctx.ProductsTransactions
                     .Where(x => x.SearchedUserID == User.SearchedUserID)
                     .ToList();
```

Where ctx object is my entity object (mapped classes of my DB).

Some users can have up to 25000 records stored from them, and the query can sometimes take up to 10-15 seconds to display the records.

P.S. the data that I'm retrieving from DB should and is read only , it cannot be manipulated in any way.

Is there any way I could speed up this query?

Edit:

Okay so I have defined my entity object in my controller like this:

```
public db_Entity ctx = new db_Entity();
```

After I pull out the data from the DB, I group it like following:

```
var prepared = allProducts.ToList();
var filteredProducts = prepared.GroupBy(x => x.ItemID).Select(x => new ResultItem()
{
    ID = x.Key,
    SaleNumber = x.Select(y => y.QuantityPurchased).Sum(),
    SaleEarning = x.Select(y => y.QuantityPurchased * y.SalePrice).Sum(),
    Title = x.Select(y => y.Title).FirstOrDefault(),
    CurrentPrice = x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.TransactionDate).Select(y=>y.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault(),
    GalleryURL = "http://somesite.com",
    SalePrice = x.Select(y => y.SalePrice).FirstOrDefault()
}).ToList();
```

After that I put the filteredProducts into a viewbag so I can show it to the end user like this:

```
ViewBag.Products = filteredProducts;
```

Do you guys need more info on the table structure?

Edit #2: Guys, many of you mentioned that I should implement indexing on SearchedUserId in my SQL table... How can I do that?

Comment: There's a million ways this could potentially be sped up, but we would need to know a whole lot more about your database/code/data/servers/etc. All we can really do now is to make sure you have an index on the `SearchedUserID` column.

Comment: From this really short code we can´t guess anything that leads to performance-issues, I can´t imagine how this single statement could be faster.

Comment: What info do you guys need,  I shall post it right away?

Comment: What I was hinting at is that this site is not a good place to ask that kind of question. we require very specific programming problem and perf questions are often very generic.

Comment: If you have an index (with up-to-date statistics) on the SearchedUserID column, this will make the most difference. Apart from that we would need a whole bunch more information... You could try posting on http://www.sqlservercentral.com/

Comment: Do you display all rows to the user? Or do you apply some sort of paging?

Comment: @TasosK. I implement te paging on view yes... Only 200 of the top selling items (in terms of quantity) are shown  to end user...

Comment: @Milney can you be more specific on how do I do that? P.S. I don't have the index on that column, It's an FK. How can I do that?

Comment: 25K Rows is **no data at all**.  If your queries take 10 seconds instead of 10ms, you probably have both a bad schema design, missing indexes *and* probably load everything in memory. Use SQL Server Profiler to capture the actual queries that are sent to the server and check the execution plan of the queries to find which are too expensive due to missing indexes

Comment: @User987 are you using LINQ to SQL or LINQ to EF? LINQ to SQL will load everything in memory if it can't convert what you wrote to SQL. Don't use it. Also, simplify your query. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL. If a query looks ugly in SQL or LINQ, it will perform very badly. You *have* to check the generated SQL statement to see what is actually getting executed

Comment: You should consider implement paging on the server, so that you wont have to load 25k rows when the page loads, and load 10, 20 or 50 rows each time.

Comment: All of those `ToList`s you have mean you are processing everything in memory instead of leveraging the database.

Comment: Paging on the server is trivial - `OrderBy(whatever).Skip(pageSize*pageNumber).Take(pageSize)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've generated a model using ADO.NET entity framework, and then perform queries on the generated model. Where ctx.ProductsTransactions is the generated class on which I perform a LINQ..

Comment: You can also replace this `x.Select(y => y.QuantityPurchased).Sum()` with this `x.Sum(y => y.QuantityPurchased)`

Comment: @DavidG excellent I shall do that. What about the indexing the FK SearchedUserId , how can I do that ?

Comment: @User987 and yet, you load **everything** in memory with ` allProducts.ToList()`, then try summarize the data. Remove all unnecessary `ToList()` calls (ie all of them) and *fix* any EF errors that complain that the query isn't supported.

Comment: @User987 I'd suggest that you write a proper SQL statement that would generate what you want *first*. Once you understand what the query should look like, write the equivalent in LINQ. Replacing `Select.Sum` with just `Sum` is only one change you need to make. Far better to create a clean query that try to fix this - the result will be the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Excellent advice ty. What about implementing the indexing on SearchedUserId FK?

Comment: It's more than just indexing on that column now. Like @PK says, you need to understand your query and how the query plan works. This makes your question far too broad for SO.

Comment: @DavidG should I make a simple stored procedure for this call then ? I mean it's just a simple select with a where statement...?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a raw query or a procedure, the same SQL will be executed. That's why you need to understand your database, indexing and how a query plan works.

Comment: @DavidG Okay I'll investigate more on this matter to fix the performance. Ty =)

Comment: paging... no 1 is going to look at all 2000 x items... problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pretty much everyone mentioned, the first thing that comes to mind is adding an index to you `SearchedUserId` column in SQL:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_SearchedUserId] 
ON ProductsTransactions ([SearchedUserId] ASC|DESC) 
ON [filegroup_or_partition_name]
```

There are a few other options to increase performance, such as fine-tuning your server platforms, hardware etc. (using flash storage will significantly improve performance, too).

Comment: amazing , ty for this! :) What should i put as filegroup or partition name? Partition name as in "C drive" or ?

Comment: When you create a SQL database, you define a filegroup or partition name (or it could be left as default). You'll have to check your database properties to find what it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want this particular query to be optimized then you want a covering index that exactly matches your extended query e.g.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductsTransactions_SearchedUserId_ItemId_etc]
    ON [ProductsTransactions]
    (
        [SearchedUserId] ASC,
        [ItemId] ASC,
        [TransactionDate] DESC,
        [SalePrice] ASC,
        [Title] ASC
    )
```

This would **maximise** the performance of the defined query but limit the indexes reusability for other queries.

---

However, if the data is truly read-only and can never change and since your query contains no variables, why not pre calculate the result and return that data directly from your application layer without a call to the database. That will be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

Don't overlook optimising this one part of your app, by NOT using your ORM tool.

An ADO.Net command will be faster and eliminate any overhead, either with a SQL query, or passing params to a stored proc.

Also, consider whether you can cache data in your app to eliminate the need for the database hit.

Comment: While there is a perf difference between using an ORM or not, I have always found it insignificant compared to setting up the db properly and writing the query correctly. I have only ever found if necessary when the ORM doesn't support a db feature you can use in the SQL.

Comment: @Mant101, from experience EF6 costs about 200ms over a hand rolled query executed with Dapper, that order of magnitude. If you care about 200 ms its worth considerng. As you imply, a badly written query can cost 10's of seconds but then, often you need control over the exact query that will be executed. Broadly, the more performance matters the less you want to use an ORM that generates SQL.

Comment: Is that running the query the first time, or subsequent times when EF has cached the expression? I've had EF queries consistently faster than 200ms so 200ms more seems suspect. I used to spend a long time optimizing db calls and honestly switching from linq to raw sql was almost never the solution.

Comment: Indeed, but the orm generated SQL may be inefficient, should have mentioned that.